# JPA - Persisting a One to Many performance

Tags: jpa

Hi,
    I'm newbie in JPA and I'm getting performance issue in a oneToMany relation persistence.
    The entities and the controllers have been generated by netbeans.
    Take a look at the piece of code below. 
    When persisting a personne,

```
profileId.getPersonSet().add(person);
```

takes about 45 secondes because my data base contain about 16000 persons. It is too much ! How could I improve this ?

```
    <pre><code>
    public class Profile implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Basic(optional = false)
        @Column(name = "profile_id", nullable = false)
        private Integer profileId;
        @Basic(optional = false)
        @Column(nullable = false, length = 60)
        private String label;
        @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "profileId", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
        private Set<Person> personSet;

        public Profile() {
        }
        .............
    </code></pre>

    <pre><code>
    public class Person implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Basic(optional = false)
        @Column(name = "person_id", nullable = false)
        private Long personId;
        @Basic(optional = false)
        @Column(name = "last_name", nullable = false, length = 60)
        private String lastName;
        @Basic(optional = false)
        @Column(name = "first_name", nullable = false, length = 60)
        private String firstName;
        @Basic(optional = false)
        @Column(nullable = false)
        @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
        private Date birthday;
        @Column(length = 60)
        private String email;
        @Column(length = 60)
        private String phone;
        @Column(name = "mobile_phone", length = 60)
        private String mobilePhone;
        @Column(length = 60)
        private String company;
        @JoinColumn(name = "profile_id", referencedColumnName = "profile_id", nullable = false)
        @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        private Profile profileId;
        @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "personId", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        ..............

    </code></pre>

    <pre><code>
    public class PersonJpaController implements Serializable {

        public PersonJpaController(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
            this.emf = emf;
        }
        private EntityManagerFactory emf = null;

        public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
            return emf.createEntityManager();
        }

        public void create(Person person) {
            EntityManager em = null;
            try {
                em = getEntityManager();
                em.getTransaction().begin();
                Profile profileId = person.getProfileId();
                if (profileId != null) {
                    profileId = em.getReference(profileId.getClass(), profileId.getProfileId());
                    person.setProfileId(profileId);
                }
                ..........................
                em.persist(person);
                if (profileId != null) {
                    profileId.getPersonSet().add(person);
                    profileId = em.merge(profileId);
                }


    ....................
</code></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove the last few lines:

```
if (profileId != null) {
    profileId.getPersonSet().add(person);
    profileId = em.merge(profileId);
}
```

These lines force JPA to load the profile, load all its persons, and add the new person to the collection. It's not needed, since the owner of the association is Person.

That said, if a profile has so many persons that it's a problem to load them all, the association should probably be modeled as a unidirectional ManyToOne association.

Answer (score 0):

Make the personSet LAZY or remove it all together as it seems too big to ever want to load.

Also change the type to List.  If you are using EclipseLink and have weaving correctly enabled then a LAZY List will not be loaded on an add() call.

Not sure why you call merge() this should not be required unless it is detached.